# how to calculate the price, subtotal and total based on given value in textbox onkeypress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have 4 textboxes, based on the given value I need to calculate everything on keyup functionality. I have used for loop on textboxes and get the value how to calculate on keyup to get the next textbox in loop and append the value in subtotal and total also i have to calculate tax based given quantity and price amount, subtotal, total should be append.

```
<td width="20%">
    <input type="text" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)"  class="" name="quan[]" id="quan[]" maxlength="2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Quantity" >
</td>
<td width="20%">
    <input type="text" class="" name="unit[]" id="unit[]" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Unit" >
</td>
<td width="20%">
    <input type="text" class="" name="tax[]" id="tax[]" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tax">
</td>
<td width="15%" colspan="1" valign="top">
    <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt" name="amt[]" id="amt[]" value="0.00" readonly>
</td>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
    <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
        <p>Subtotal</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
        <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
        <p>Savings to Customer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
        <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt" placeholder="Enter Amount...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
        <p><strong>Grand Total</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
        <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt bald" readonly>
    </div>
</div>


var quantity = document.getElementsByName("quan[]");
var unit_level = document.getElementsByName("unit[]");
var tax = document.getElementsByName("tax[]");  

for ( var i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++ ){
    $(quantity[i]).on("keyup blur",function(){

        var get_val_quant = $(this).val();

        if($(this).val()==0){
            //alert("value should be greater than zero");
            document.getElementById('quantity_error').innerHTML="Please enter number greater than zero"; 
            $("#quantity_error").removeClass('field_validation_error hidden');
            $("#quantity_error").addClass('field_validation_error');
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('quantity_error').innerHTML=""; 
            $("#quantity_error").removeClass('field_validation_error');
            $("#quantity_error").addClass('field_validation_error hidden');
        }
    })

    //console.log(unit_level[i]);
    $(unit_level[i]).on("keyup blur",function(){                
        var get_unit_price = $(this).val();
        if($(this).val()==0){
            //alert("value should be greater than zero");
        document.getElementById('unit_error').innerHTML="Please enter number greater than zero"; 
            $("#unit_error").removeClass('field_validation_error hidden');
            $("#unit_error").addClass('field_validation_error');
            return false;
        } else if(get_unit_price!=0){
            alert((quantity[i]).value());
            return false;

        } else{
            document.getElementById('unit_error').innerHTML=""; 
            $("#unit_error").removeClass('field_validation_error');
            $("#unit_error").addClass('field_validation_error hidden');
        }
    });

    $(tax[i]).on("keyup blur",function(){               
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peL7er72/)

Comment: First, you are mixing `document.getElementById()` statements with `$()`. Second, it's always better to use classes (e.g. `txtboxes`) for this purpose, third could you please clarify in plain English what you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: 1. Reformat code to make it easier to read. 2. Use punctucation to improce readabililty of your question, because I cannot understand it.

Comment: Instead of binding events through looping, apply class and bind events based on that class.

Comment: @Mattias Lindberg now i have reformatted my code. CAnyou able to read it for example you can see http://jsfiddle.net/c6yfS/1/

Comment: @vara prasad. It will be in loop if i apply class it will difficult to the get the row value right there will be more rows on adding

Comment: it's not difficult to get the values because you will get reference object of each row so that you can find and fetch the values and one more thing is if rows will be adding dynamically then you need to manually bind events for each row added.

Comment: Could you show me example

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why not just use it as it will make things a lot easier than mixing it with pure js

Comment: @Parker, check this url `https://jsfiddle.net/dv3L8n73/`

Answer (score 0):

I have taken 2 static rows with `unit,quantity,tax` text boxes and last textbox is for total amount for each row. Whenever any changes in any of those 3values it will calculate related price and update in the last textbox And also subtotal,grandtotal with respect to the customer savings value(if any).

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>            
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="text" class="key-up-event" name="quan[]" id="quan[]" maxlength="2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Quantity" >
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="text" class="key-up-event" name="unit[]" id="unit[]" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Unit" >
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="text" class="key-up-event" name="tax[]" id="tax[]" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tax">
            </td>
            <td width="15%" colspan="1" valign="top">
                <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt" name="amt[]" id="amt[]" value="0.00" readonly>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="text" class="key-up-event" name="quan[]" id="quan[]" maxlength="2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Quantity" >
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="text" class="key-up-event" name="unit[]" id="unit[]" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Unit" >
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <input type="text" class="key-up-event" name="tax[]" id="tax[]" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tax">
            </td>
            <td width="15%" colspan="1" valign="top">
                <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt" name="amt[]" id="amt[]" value="0.00" readonly>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            <p>Subtotal</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
            <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt" id="subttot" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            <p>Savings to Customer</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
            <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt" id="savngs" placeholder="Enter Amount...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
            <p><strong>Grand Total</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
            <input type="text" class="dollar different_amt bald" id="fintot" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".key-up-event").on("keyup blur", function(){
        if ($(this).attr("name") == "quan[]") {
            var ind = $("input[name='quan[]']").index(this);                
        } else if ($(this).attr("name") == "unit[]") {
            var ind = $("input[name='unit[]']").index(this);
        } else if ($(this).attr("name") == "tax[]") {
            var ind = $("input[name='tax[]']").index(this);
        }

        var quan, unit, tax, amt;
        quan = parseFloat($("input[name='quan[]']:eq("+ind+")").val());
        quan = (isNaN(quan)) ? 0 : quan;
        unit = parseFloat($("input[name='unit[]']:eq("+ind+")").val());
        unit = (isNaN(unit)) ? 0 : unit;
        tax = parseFloat($("input[name='tax[]']:eq("+ind+")").val());
        tax = (isNaN(tax)) ? 0 : tax;
        amt = quan*unit + tax;

        $("input[name='amt[]']:eq("+ind+")").val(amt)

        subtotal();
    });

    function subtotal() {
        var tot = 0;
        $("input[name='amt[]']").each(function(){
            tot += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $("#subttot").val(tot)
        finaltotal();
    }

    $("#savngs").on("keyup blur", function(){
        finaltotal();
    });

    function finaltotal() {
        var tot = 0;
        var subtot = parseFloat($("#subttot").val());
        subtot = (isNaN(subtot)) ? 0 : subtot;
        var savngs = parseFloat($("#savngs").val());
        savngs = (isNaN(savngs)) ? 0 : savngs;
        tot = subtot-savngs;
        $("#fintot").val(tot)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can You Explain What Your Code Do. What Are The Changes Have You Done In This Code. *Participate in making answer in better format by describing your code.*